# Memory management in IBM360

Tags: architecture, operating-system

I'm having trouble understanding the following paragraph from Modern Operating System book:

*"Memory was divided into 2-KB blocks and each was assigned a 4-bit protection key held in special registers inside the CPU. A machine with a 1-MB memory needed only 512 of these 4-bit registers for a total of 256 bytes of key storage. The PSW (Program Status Word) also contained a 4-bit key."*

512 of 4-bit registers can index 512*2^4 entries (a 4-bit register can address 2^4 entries), so the memory should be 512*2^4*8 = 64kb? (each entry is 8-bit). Why is that 1Mb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

512 blocks = 2^9 blocks

Block size = 2^11 = 2KB

2kb * 512 blocks = 2^11 * 2^9 = 2^20 = 1-MB

The 4-big registers do not address anything. The are the protections bits for a 2KB block.